# Salesforce Master-Detail Relationship

Tags: salesforce, master-detail

I have two objects: **House** and **Owner**

Owner has a field "ID", House has a field "Owner_ID", how do I link "Owner_ID" to the "ID" field in Owner using a Master-Detail relationship in the Salesforce under schema builder?

When I create a new M-D relationship in House, It doesn't have a selection box to let me set which field does a M-D relationship refer to in Owner. It defaulted to the "Owner Name" field. (ie. when I insert a new House, I can search for the owner by "Owner Name", but cannot search for the owner by "ID")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Master Detail relationships only link to the ID field of the parent record — you can't change this. That said, the UI uses the names for the convenience of users which is why you're not able to search via ID there.

Comment: Ah i see...thanks for clearing this up. However the problem is that I already have House.OwnerID and Owner.ID linked in a mysql database which I'm trying to import into SF. However the SF id field doesn't seem to accept anything less than 15char. Is there a way for me to import and keep the relationship? Thanks!

Comment: Salesforce IDs have a specific format and come in two forms, one 15 characters and one 18 (the 15 character version is case sensitive). What you need to do is load your header records into salesforce, loading your external ID into a custom field marked as such.

Then extract the records using data loader or similar, and use a vlookup to map the MD field on your child records to the Salesforce IDs on their corresponding parent records. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Summer'12, it is possible to change the parent record of a child record:

#### How to reparent:

To enable this option, select the Allow reparenting option in the master-detail relationship field definition.

#### Reference:

https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Summer12/master+detail+relationship+expands